# Git diff gives 'No such path' error when I specify a directory

Tags: git

My repository looks like below:

application (main directory)

- component_1 (sub directory)
- component_2 (sub directory)

I want to take the difference between origin/release/version_1.1 vs origin/release/version_1.2

So I execute this command:

```
git diff origin/release/version_1.1 origin/release/version_1.2
```

This showed me the expected difference.

Now I want to get the diff only on component_1 directory.

So I used the below command

```
git diff component_1 origin/release/version_1.1 origin/release/version_1.2
```

But now I get the following error:

```
fatal: origin/release/version_1.1: no such path in the working tree.
Use 'git <command> -- <path>...' to specify paths that do not exist locally.
```

Can you please help me troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the docs, the syntax here looks like:

```
git diff [<options>] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>…​]
```

Note that this expects the first two parameters to be git refs.  As this (and your error message) suggests, you have to specify the directory like:

```
git diff origin/release/version_1.1 origin/release/version_1.2 -- component_1
```

(You can probably get away without the `--`, but it helps prevent ambiguity.)